# Multiple deployment configurations for React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm wanting to setup a proper deployment pipeline for our apps using React Native so that for example in iOS we have a:

1. Debug version for the development team
2. Internal Release UAT version
3. Release Production version

Now with the default setup, using the Schema "Debug" and "Release" allows for 1 and 3 but how can I add another for point 2 which will still make React Native build as a release?

We're using Code-Push and I want to have some separate config for point 2 and 3 which is why I am asking this question.  Same will go for Android too.